# End edition signal of a QLineEdit in a QTableView

Tags: pyqt

I've been facing a problem for several days now. I'm using a QTableView to display data from a model. I activated the complete line selection when the user click on a cell, to make the interface user friendly:
    self.tableau.selectRow(element.row())

But, when the user presses F2, I would like to edit only the column 1. So, the expected behavior is:

- if I selected the column 4, this one is not editable
- if I press F2 when column 4 is selected, the column 1 is edited

But with the complete row selection, F2 can not know which cell is selected. So, I re-implemented the event handler:

```py
def keyPressEvent(self, e):
    """It reimplements event management in this method """

    # TODO: find a way to re-select the cell after editing

    # We get the name of current file
    nom_courant = self.tableau.model().index(self.row_selected, 1).data()
    print(nom_courant)

    if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_F2:

        try:
            # We edit the cell name of the selected line
            #http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157688/specifying-an-index-in-qtableview-with-pyqt
            self.tableau.edit(self.tableau.model().index(self.row_selected, 1))
        except:
            print("Pas de cell sélectionnée")
            pass

    # It retrieves the new file name. CAN NOT do in the
    # if the model is not updated yet.
    nouveau_nom = self.tableau.model().index(self.row_selected, 1).data()
    print(nouveau_nom)

    # Call the fct renaming only if the name has changed
    if nom_courant != nouveau_nom:
        #liste.renameFile(self.current_video, self.tableau.model().index(self.row_selected, 1).data())
        print("entropie")
```

The matter now is this line:

```
self.tableau.edit(self.tableau.model().index(self.row_selected, 1))
```

I have no way to detect the end of the edition of the QLineEdit generated, and I need it to perform actions on the new content of the cell edited, because nouveau_nom is not updated if no keyboard event occurs.

Do you have an idea about how to get the end edition signal ?

(Please forgive my english, I'm french...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need to actually intercept and change the cell selection to a row selection. You can just [set the behavior](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qabstractitemview.html#setSelectionBehavior) on the view:

```
self.tableau.setSelectionBehavior(self.tableau.SelectRows)
```

This will automatically select rows.

When you use a custom QLineEdit widgets in your table, then you need to connect [QLineEdit.editingFinished()](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qlineedit.html#editingFinished) to whatever handler you want. Most likely you want it to call `dataChanged` on your model.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, especially setSelectionBehavior. The display is better with that moreover.

And finally, I subclassed my view, and redefined createEditor, to handle properly the QLineEdits. I connected returnPressed to others methods. Thanks for you advices, very helpfull.